# Subset of edges with a different color

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks, color

I want to color a subset of the edges of my graph with a different color. 
My graph currently has a large number of edges, so the following is just a toy example

```
s = {1->2,1->3}
g = {1->2, 1->3,3->4,4->1}
GraphPlot[g,VertexLabeling->True]
```

[image]

Here `s` is a subset of `g` I would like to tell `GraphPlot` to plot the edges 
in `s` with a different color, and make the edges of `s` directed.

How to do this?

---

EDIT:

The closest I have coming after looking at some answer to another question 
on this site is

```
s = {{1,2},{1,3}}
g = {1->2, 1->3,3->4,4->1}
GraphPlot[g,VertexLabeling->True,EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[
     Intersection[s, {#2}] != {}, {Red ,Arrow[#1, .1]}, 
                                  {Blue,Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]
```

[image]

However, since I want the complement of the set `s` in `g` to be represented
as blue segment (and not an arrow) I am not sure what I should write in place
of `Arrow` inside `{Blue,Arrow[#1, .1]}` above.

Comment: THere are several examples in the documentation for `VertexRenderingFunction`. The help file will show you how to apply it.

Comment: Something like `HighlightGraph[Graph[{1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}], {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3}]`?

Comment: @J. M. Yes almost, like that.However, please see edit.

Comment: `s = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}}
g = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1}
GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[
     Intersection[s, {#2}] != {}, {Red, Line[#1]}, {Blue, 
      Arrow[#1, .1]}] &)]`

Comment: @belisarius That code doesn't work for me but if it solves the question I think you should post it, modified as to work, as an answer.

Comment: @C. E. I posted it as a comment because I'm not sure if it answers the question. Since the OP hasn't logged on for three months now, perhaps we will never know

Comment: @belisarius I initiated a vote to close this question then, as it is unclear what he is asking for.

Comment: @C. E. I posted an answer, let's see if the community thinks it has some value

Answer (score 6):

```
s = {{1, 2}, {1, 3}};
g = {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3, 3 -> 4, 4 -> 1} ; 
GraphPlot[g, VertexLabeling -> True, 
          EdgeRenderingFunction -> (If[s ⋂ {#2} != {}, {Red, Arrow[#1, .1]}, {Blue, Line[#1]}] &)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 0):

Using `Graph` with options `EdgeStyle`:

```
Graph[g, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram",
  EdgeStyle -> {_ -> Directive[Arrowheads[0], Blue],
     ## & @@ Thread[s -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]]}]
```

[image]

Same result with a combination of options `EdgeStyle` and `EdgeShapeFunction`:

```
EdgeStyle -> Prepend[Thread[s -> Directive[Opacity[1], Thick, Red]], _ -> Blue]
```

and

```
EdgeShapeFunction -> Prepend[Thread[s -> "Arrow"], _ -> "Line"]
```

Answer (score 0):

[`HighlightGraph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HighlightGraph.html) has been mentioned in the comments, and you responded to that comment, but it is still not clear to me when you cannot use this function.

```
HighlightGraph[
 Graph[g, GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram", EdgeStyle -> Blue],
 Style[s, Red]
]
```

[image]

- `GraphStyle -> "VintageDiagram"` uses the style of `GraphPlot` with `Graph`
- `EdgeStyle -> Blue` makes the default edge colour blue
- `HighlightGraph[..., Style[s, Red]]` highlights the edges listed in `s` in `Red`.